# Spock Mock not returning any data

Tags: unit-testing, spock

I have a class which adds features to categories of products in the same category and prices based on the productCode of the product. I have a List of List of products in the same category and productCode for which the same price and category should be added. However, when I create a mock for the ProductDecorator it fails to return any products. I am using Lombok's @EqualsAndHashCode.Include on productCode in both classes

Here is the code

```java
public class ProductDetail {
  String productCode;
  String category;
  Double price;

  public String getProductCode() {
    return productCode;
  }
}
```

```java
class Product {
  String name;
  String productCode;
  String category;
  Double price;

  String getProductCode() {
    return productCode;
  }

  public Product addDetail(String category, Double price) {
    this.category = category;
    this.price = price;
    return this;
  }
}
```

```java
public class ProductDecorator {
  List<Product> addProductFeature(List<Product> products, List<ProductDetail> details) {
    List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
    products.forEach(product -> {
      details.forEach(detail -> {
        if (product.getProductCode().equals(detail.getProductCode())) {
          Product p = product.addDetail(detail.category, detail.price);
          productList.add(p);
        }
      });
    });
    return productList;
  }
}
```

```java
  // 3 Products and 3 product details objects that match
  List<List<Product>> products = getProducts()
  List<ProductDetail> productDetailList = getProductDetails()

  ProductDecorator productDecorator = Mock()
  // Returns null all the time for all, just showing the first one
  productDecorator.addProductFeature(products[0],productDetailList)>>[products[0]]
```

How do I successfully mock the decorator to match. I think it is not matching because of some equality issues.I tried using underscores but that did not work either. I'd be grateful for a solution to thsi problem

Comment: Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you. Specifically, you have problems with a Spock test, but are not showing the complete test. You think you have problems with Lombok, but are not showing any Lombok details here. Why are you hiding the two things you are asking about? That does not make any sense.

Comment: Please also use one code block per class, do not mash up all into one. I just fixed that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, it works like this, so probably your original code looks different:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q77412076;

import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.ToString;

@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public class ProductDetail {
  String productCode;
  String category;
  Double price;

  String getProductCode() {
    return productCode;
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q77412076;

import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.ToString;

@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public class Product {
  String name;
  String productCode;
  String category;
  Double price;

  String getProductCode() {
    return productCode;
  }

  Product addDetail(String category, Double price) {
    this.category = category;
    this.price = price;
    return this;
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q77412076;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ProductDecorator {
  List<Product> addProductFeature(List<Product> products, List<ProductDetail> details) {
    List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
    products.forEach(product -> {
      details.forEach(detail -> {
        if (product.getProductCode().equals(detail.getProductCode())) {
          Product p = product.addDetail(detail.category, detail.price);
          productList.add(p);
        }
      });
    });
    return productList;
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q77412076

import spock.lang.Specification

class ProductDetailTest extends Specification {
  def 'test without mock'() {
    expect:
    new ProductDecorator().addProductFeature(products[0], productDetails) == [
      new Product(name: 'One', productCode: 'XY-1', category: 'vegetables', price: 12.34),
      new Product(name: 'Two', productCode: 'AB-2', category: 'flowers', price: 23.45),
      new Product(name: 'Three', productCode: 'QR-3', category: 'vegetables', price: 34.56)
    ]
    new ProductDecorator().addProductFeature(products[1], productDetails) == [
      new Product(name: 'Four', productCode: 'XY-1', category: 'vegetables', price: 12.34),
      new Product(name: 'Five', productCode: 'AB-2', category: 'flowers', price: 23.45),
      new Product(name: 'Six', productCode: 'QR-3', category: 'vegetables', price: 34.56)
    ]
  }

  def 'test with mock'() {
    given:
    ProductDecorator productDecorator = Mock()
    productDecorator.addProductFeature(products[0], productDetails) >> products[0]

    expect:
    productDecorator.addProductFeature(products[0], productDetails) == products[0]
    productDecorator.addProductFeature(products[1], productDetails) == null
  }

  List<List<Product>> getProducts() {
    [
      [
        new Product(name: 'One', productCode: 'XY-1'),
        new Product(name: 'Two', productCode: 'AB-2'),
        new Product(name: 'Three', productCode: 'QR-3')
      ],
      [
        new Product(name: 'Four', productCode: 'XY-1'),
        new Product(name: 'Five', productCode: 'AB-2'),
        new Product(name: 'Six', productCode: 'QR-3')
      ]
    ]
  }

  List<ProductDetail> getProductDetails() {
    [
      new ProductDetail(productCode: 'XY-1', category: 'vegetables', price: 12.34),
      new ProductDetail(productCode: 'AB-2', category: 'flowers', price: 23.45),
      new ProductDetail(productCode: 'QR-3', category: 'vegetables', price: 34.56)
    ]
  }
}
```

Please note: The mock should return `products[0]` rather than `[products[0]]`, because `ProductDecorator.addProductFeature` returns `List<Product>`, not `List<List<Product>>`. But that is not the root cause of your problem.

---

Try it in the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&codez=eNq1Vltv2jAUfs-v8BuJBFa5tEjVQOva8bRpF_qwqUKTl5hgNcSp7UAR4r_vJLFzBTpoywMk5_L55PvOOSEi7iPxKfIolq6Il3-WRCoqsFTg4Csq5gFf46fhcNDtXQyvLIstIy4U8gXnqw1WgoRyzsUS35KQh8wlgYmQEXcfcUBCH08j6rI5OBXjoWW5AZESfRfci111RxVhwT2VCtFnRUNPoko42loIqpujlkpi1kwteKzQEsBbtpN6EWRCirpOr0O6LrBdLojiwnYw8TxtnVCiYkHtKLuVDxezNorK1UgHjUboIYWrANohWdJr1PoW0laec8u9xPbrd6cLRqia-lxswLKiPsD9DahMg5kLYd0e7g-c9mHo-zVvQN986vSq0IkqVJRwe308uDyKuxC0WfSPn53-y0X3B_jyykmxZ2dy3D2Z4wmPxXuRPGEr-i4sT9nz23C8sxptX-t5H54hzFq-LkXBtDGM0FdItjP8uvfU2RiPUclvNSbwtfjQF2X8UyEPtFoYB4Eh9guT6kP6pUHgkUASfSNzjk17mt_TlkHeKKcN-gtph-fY0Xmz9v-UfXi-jhdweHaO5x0cjbzsavOX5cl0LGuklW0oVdlMSYj9pgtkL-ZrFsdewDM3BtD2sXgN73nLplxNlWChXxaiMJoTwXLHYzguO-sYchkzUfrME6x8iyEYbc1KLaddSTHKqwWT2ITAoiudoJ1pOBrpk4zZUFbjyWzMba0Fx6i5cqp-s4Dae1vXM6soq3pvamKEOpP2uBGCbNKgcXVrSwx_tz4Td2FvjQl1xrqx9CGlkMxSRCDE5si0Gy7mKVEJ3uD0KSYwVVlWw-2Y6rOPESxC-cLGhXgaoxBPGzLxSjClh0_S7ahw7vTVLjPtKkwkCVrEfwHKakM).

There, I used the Groovy equivalent of your Lombok annotations for simplicity's sake. `@Canonical` is like a combination of `@ToString`, `@EqualsAndHashCode` and `@TupleConstructor`. While recreating your situation, I was also printing values, hence the wish to have nice `toString()` methods. I also converted your lambdas into Groovy closures. Lambdas are fine in Groovy 4, but closures also work in older Groovy versions.

Comment: **Update:** I added a link for a complete reproducer in the GWC (Groovy Web Console).

Comment: @BreenDeen, thanks for accepting my answer. But my Spock test code is identical to your snippet. If my answer solves your problem, please briefly comment on what was different in your project, so other readers understand what the problem for you was.